# Square brackets breaking regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to learning regex, and I came across a problem that I solved, although I'm not sure why it was a problem and would just like to learn a bit more!

I'm using Python for my regex statement. The relevant portion of text to be captured is (I've changed the exact numbers, but this is what it looks like)

```
Evaluation Type: InterimContract Percent Complete: 30%Period of Performance Being Assessed: 05/27/2013 -
```

I'm looking to capture `Interim` and `05/27/2013`. The regex that I was using that did NOT work was

```
match = re.search(
"Evaluation Type:[\s\n]*(.*?)[\s\n]*Contract Percent[.]*"
"Period of Performance Being Assessed:[\s\n]*(.*?)[\s\n]*-"
, page_content)
```

The code that does work is

```
match = re.search(
"Evaluation Type:[\s\n]*(.*?)[\s\n]*Contract Percent.*"
"Period of Performance Being Assessed:[\s\n]*(.*?)[\s\n]*-"
, page_content)
```

(as you may notice, the difference is that I removed the square brackets around the `.` at the end of line 2.

I understand that the brackets weren't actually needed (just helped me visualize it as I'm creating the regex) but I'm not sure why they broke it. I was getting no match with the first set of code, while a perfect match with the second. I'm sure it's some simple little thing, but I couldn't find what would be breaking from my searches online (although it could be that I don't understand enough in depth to know what I'm looking for)

Comment: Characters inside square brackets are treated as literals.  Hence, `[.]*` means a literal dot, zero or more times, while `.*` means _any_ character zero or more times.  It should be clear to you that the former won't match your input, while the latter (apparently) does.

Comment: Your RE is overcomplicated, all of your square brackets are not needed and don't actually do what you intended them to do. In fact, this RE - `Type:\s*(.*?)\s*Contract.*Assessed:\s*(.*?)\s*-` will give you the exact same result.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it would be more helpful if you include that link as a comment rather than marking it as a duplicate. That compilation of links isn't very helpful unless you know what you are looking for (which beginners like me don't). If I was simply asking for regex code I could understand marking as a duplicate, but I was looking for an explanation which is something that that link can't help with (I didn't know which link would help me solve my problem because I didn't really understand what the problem was)

Comment: You are looking for the details on the 2 regex patterns. Just go to http://regex101.com, and you will see immediately where the problem is. That post provides the link to regex101 and many other posts that help. I have added another close reason that deals with your case exactly (the link is also present in the *What does this regex mean* post).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `[.]*` means 0 or more dot
- `.*` means 0 or more any character but newline.

A dot inside a character class loses its special meaning.

Comment: Oh that makes so much more sense now! Does this apply only to the dot or are there other characters that lose their meaning (such as ^)?

Comment: @glibdud: Thanks for editing ;)

Comment: @MarkR See the [re documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax); specifically, the explanation of the `[]` special characters.

Comment: @MarkR: many special characters change their meaning when inside charcater class, `^` have another meaning, it means strat of string but in char class, it negate the conyent of the char class, `[^abc]` means any charcater that IS NOT a or b or c

Comment: Oh great, now I understand better what the documentation was saying. It is just a bit hard to understand when first trying it out